# View SMS in Windows Mobile via Managed Code

Tags: windows-mobile, sms

In the Windows Mobile SDK, there is a MessagingApplication class in Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook that has a method "DisplayComposeForm" that allows you to bring up the default compose dialog for sending an SMS.

I need a way to display the default message viewing dialog from managed code. I.e. i've retrieved the message via MAPI, but now I want to show it using the default message viewer in Windows Mobile.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to some clever googling, I've stumbled on the answer.

Use P/Invoke to access the [MailDisplayMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415500.aspx) method in the MAPI API.

The P/Invoke signature is as follows:

```
[DllImport("cemapi.dll")]
internal static extern int MailDisplayMessage(byte[] lpEntryID, int cbEntryID);
```

For managed access to the message stores, you can use the free [MAPIdotnet](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/PocketPCandSmartphone.aspx) project.